# cs50 pset 5 speller. valgrind shows no memory leak, but check 50 says valgrind fail

Tags: valgrind, cs50

My code passes all check 50 test except Valgrind. When I run Valgrind it says error summary 0 errors from 0 context.

The program is running fine otherwise. Don't know where to start debugging.

Comment: Does  valgrind give the same result with the large and small dictionary? If you notice in the check50 results, all tests are done on a "small" dictionary (though necessarily the one in the distro code).

Comment: Make sure that you are doing exactly the same as the "check 50" test.